WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager (wso2is-6.1.0) - Old Users Not Getting Locked After Invalid Login Attempts
I am using wso2is-6.1.0 as a key manager to wso2am-4.3.0. I have configured the shared_db and taken a db dump from an existing shared_db which is utilized by an older version, in order to get the existing users to the new cluster.
I followed the below mentioned documentation to configure account locking on multiple failed attempts.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.1.0/guides/identity-lifecycles/lock-accounts-by-failed-login-attempts/
However, when the older users are tried with multiple failed login attempts, the users do not get locked even after enabling the account locking policy. This is not the case for newly created users.
A direction to resolve this issue is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
